# Several input checkbox using one JS with different var

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 input checkboxes. Each of them displays a div if checked. Because the three has the same JS I have decided to have just one JS including 3 variables (one per input) but it is not working. Before I had three independent JS and it worked fine.

**CODE**

```js
document.getElementById()

var cb1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1'); checkbox1.onchange = {
if (checkbox1.checked) {
  course1.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  course1.style.display = 'none';
};
var cb2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2'); checkbox2.onchange = {
if (checkbox2.checked) {
  course2.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  course2.style.display = 'none';
};
var cb3 = document.getElementById('checkbox3'); checkbox3.onchange = {
if (checkbox3.checked) {
  course3.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  course3.style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> Course 1
  </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"> Course 2
  </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"> Course 3
  </label>
</form>
<br>
<div id ="course1">
  Text course 1 
</div>
<br>
<div id ="course2">
  Text course 2 
</div>
<br>
<div id ="course3">
  Text course 3 
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/antonioagar1/pen/YOwBeE?editors=1010

Comment: why are you using checkbox1.onchange when your var is cb1 ?

Comment: In the fiddle and in the snippet (that is the same code) you have errors being thrown, open console log to see

Comment: there are lot syntax errors  and updated codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mGEbeR?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing your syntax errors (identation is very imporant, if it was correct in your code you would had see that you have many if statements not closing correclty)

Well, besides those errors, I managed a way to you that you only need a single function to achieve your desired result.

If you see in the HTML part, you'll note that I added some new attributes to checkboxes and divs, called `data-idCheck`, where the checkbox with `data-idCheck` will display the `div` whose have that same attribute.

Check below to see if my code helps you.

```js
var cb1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
cb1.onchange = checkChecked;
var cb2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
cb2.onchange = checkChecked;
var cb3 = document.getElementById('checkbox3');
cb3.onchange = checkChecked;

function checkChecked(){  
  let idCheck = this.getAttribute("data-idCheck");
  let relatedDiv = document.querySelector("div[data-idCheck='" + idCheck + "']");
  if (this.checked) {  
      relatedDiv.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      relatedDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.hiddenDiv{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" data-idCheck="1"> Course 1
  </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" data-idCheck="2"> Course 2
  </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" data-idCheck="3"> Course 3
  </label>
</form>
<br>
<div id ="course1" class="hiddenDiv" data-idCheck="1">
  Text course 1 
</div>
<br>
<div id ="course2" class="hiddenDiv"  data-idCheck="2">
  Text course 2 
</div>
<br>
<div id ="course3" class="hiddenDiv"  data-idCheck="3">
  Text course 3 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Calvin, this is exactly what I needed. I think it is quite advanced for me, but I understand it. Obrigado, thanks so much!